# How many people can a sealed 3x1x1 km biome support?

Tags: biology, space-travel, spaceships, bio-mechanics

**Question Context :**

[Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars) second moon [Deimos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deimos_(moon)) has been converted into a generation ship.

A considerable portion of its mass has been shaved off during the process & ejected backwards along its path by [Railgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun) to help increase orbital velocity (if we need additional thrust to break orbit, perhaps nuclear explosions in a concave ablation shield could be used).

It's now a stubby rough formed cylindre with a length of at least 11 km & a width of some 5 km or more in which we've excavated 10 tunnels each 3 km long in two rows 1 km apart (so like 5 tubes with a 1 km plug in the middle of each strapped around a central tube).

> *Which leaves a 1 km thickness of rock to shield against radiation with an extra 1 km front & back (so 2 km there), the main propulsion envisioned is that of [project orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)), so the rear thickness can be considered additional shock absorption & ablation shielding.*

This cylinder spins around its short axis fast enough to keep things in the tunnels on the 'ground'

**The Question Itself :**

Assuming our 3 km tubes are 1 km in diameter (allowing for space for the soil, water & plants etc), how many people can one plausibly support if its a sealed biome using no substantial technology?

*The biome intended is a temperate climate without hydroponics using ordinary animals & plants.*

*When I say no significant technology I don't include simple management like burning a bit of dead wood if CO2 is low to put more into the air to encourage plant growth.*

*Edit : adequate lighting is simply assumed at this point.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zero, since no light source has been specified, and those are pretty darn advanced.

However, assuming earth-like lighting, we can leverage Biosphere 2 as our one data point, as it is the only real attempt at a sealed biome for humans.  It was 3.14 acres and housed eight people.  One of your tubes has *roughly* 750 acres of space (assuming you don't try to stack layers, which would be difficult if your light source wasn't friendly for that.  That suggests roughly 2,000 people.

Of course, Biosphere 2 fell apart in two years with people nearly starving inside, and your generation ship is intended to last quite a lot longer.  You should probably load it lighter than that.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, lighting edit made.

Comment: _Of course, Biosphere 2 fell apart in two years_ : which is why the habitats are the first thing built & have several generations to get fine tuned while in use simply as an orbiting habitat that can receive supplies from Mars while the rest of the work is done & then until they get it right, no doubt that could take a long time ;)

Comment: Aha! thanks, you got my brain flowing with that, I assume you took a cross section & went 3 km x 1 km for the floor space getting [3 000 000 m2](https://www.google.com/search?q=3+km+times+1+km&rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&oq=3+km+times+1+km&aqs=chrome..69i57j6.8687j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which is around [741.3 acres](https://www.google.com/search?q=3+000+000+m2+in+acres&rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&oq=3+000+000+m2+in+acres&aqs=chrome..69i57.4329j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), what was your population per acre source? .. 1/2

Comment: Because the first link I found was this one which suggests 0.5 acres per person without livestock or 1.5 acres if you include grazing for livestock .. so 1480 people or 493 people .. 2/2

Comment: Why would you not use hydroponics? Conventional agriculture is hideously inefficient in comparison, and moving large masses of dirt interstellar distances is really wasteful.

Comment: @RichardSmith : Because they're going to be in there a damn long time & we want them to be comfortable & happy don't we ~ there is enough additional space lying around that hydroponics & other stuff can be fitted in comfortably as well but the intent should be for those to be back up systems rather than for constant use.

Comment: @Pelinore It did work out to roughly 1/2 person per acre.  I don't know all of the decisions that went into the design of Biosphere 2, but its probably no accident.  As for the surface area, that is what I did.  I could have been more precise, or done stacking, but it seemed like a decent first cut.  Within the error margins of predicting advanced technology, that's for sure =D

Comment: Is this calculating the total surface area of the tube, because the inhabitable portion will be less, maybe a third (the portion in the down direction)

Comment: Note that 2000 people is so small a population that the question of sufficient genetic diversity becomes quite important. It's not exactly known what size population is needed to prevent inbreeding defects over generations, but 2000 is a plausible lower limit. Author should consider addressing this at some point

Comment: @Innovine : [50/500 rule](https://www.britannica.com/science/50-500-rule) ~ 50 is sufficient to avoid inbreeding / 500 enough to avoid genetic drift ~ so 2000 should be more than OK, especially for beings intelligently enough to keep track of ancestry records & apply them to relationships & diversity .. even more so if they've the tech to test for & spot lethal recessives & the like, as we have .. add to that that any sensible generation ship will also have frozen stocks of sperm & ova to inject a little extra diversity as needed & it's definitely not a problem.

Comment: @Innovine : _surface area of the tube_ : no, Cort simply took the diameter of the tube & multiplied by its length (so 3 km x 1 km) : half the [circumference](https://www.google.com/search?q=circumference+of+a+circle+calculator&rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&oq=circumference+of+a+circle&aqs=chrome.7.69i59l3j69i57j0l4.26094j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) would be 1.57 km .. but allowing for the steepening gradient of the tubes sides making it harder to stop things slipping down/off 1 km probably works out about right anyway.

Comment: @Innovine Pelinore is correct.  In theory I could get more surface area by using the correct equations, but when accounting for all of the other factors involved in a biome, it's not clear how much of that pi*r*h surface area I could get.  I stuck to diameter * length because it was a very simple number, and good enough for a rough estimate.  I trust the engineers making this will use better numbers (perhaps they'll just round pi to 3 =D )